# How to extend in Lightswitch a query that returns only leaf nodes of a tree?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In Microsoft Lightswitch I have a self-referencing table like this:

```
Courses {CourseID int, ParentID int, CourseName string}
```

In a LightSwitch screen I have a drop-down box that should show only the leaf courses.

I created a LeafCourses query and I am trying to extend it so it returns only leaf nodes, something like the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE CourseId NOT IN  
(    
SELECT ParentID FROM Courses WHERE ParentID is NOT NULL     
)
```

This is what I have (not working):

```
    partial void LeafCourses_PreprocessQuery(string Parameter, ref IQueryable<Cours> query)  
    {  
        query = from Cours c1 in query  
                where  
                !(from Cours c2 in this.Courses  
                  select c2.Cours1.CourseId  
                  ).Contains(c1.CourseId)  
                select c1;  
    }
```

Comment: Justin Anderson provided the answer:
To get this, code will need to be written in the PreprocessQuery method, but it's very simple:
 
 
` 
partial void LeafCourses_PreprocessQuery(string Parameter, ref IQueryable<Cours> query) 
{ 
 query = query.Where(c => !c.ChildCourses.Any());
}
`
where ChildCourses is the name of the navigation property on the Cours entity that represents the collection of child courses.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is long ago and you might already have the solution, but still:

As far as I understand your data model, the inner select would be sufficient:

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE parentid IS NOT NULL
```

That gives you all the rows that have a parent row (which would be your leaf nodes).

Using LINQ in the LightSwitch PreprocessQuery() this would be something like:

```
query = query.Where<Cours>(c => c.ParentId != null);
```

or not using lambda:

```
query = from c in query where c.ParentId != null select c;
```

This works even if you have no ".ChildCourses", which you apparently don't.